# VueJS change links of script files in index.html

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I created a simple app with VueJS and run it on a plattform.

Unfortunately the JS files can not be found.

The index.html searches here:

```
http://homepage.de:8080/static/js/app.b22ce679862c47a75225.js
```

But the files are here:

```
http://homepage.de:8080/app_direct/vue/static/js/app.b22ce679862c47a75225.js
```

Is there a way to change some parameters in a file to link to the correct source?

I used this old way to create my vue app if it matters (I do not have a `vue-config.js`).

```
$ npm install -g vue-cli
$ vue init webpack my-project
```

I then dockerize it with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install -g http-server

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

Comment: Think you need to look for a config for the baseUrl

Comment: where do I find that?

Comment: maybe you need setup the web server root to your app root

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath